# Export all trusted certificates on Windows from the command line as PEM or DER

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, powershell, certificate

I need to export all trusted certificates with `certutil` from the following stores:

- My
- Root
- Trust
- CA
- AuthRoot

However I have trouble understanding the documentation and I am not an expert with certutil... Any idea whether any of these options are possible:

- Print the certificate in the console outpout in PEM (base64 encoded string) format
- Export to a directory as PEM format
- Export to a directory as DER (binary) format

If it is possible could you provide examples how to achieve it?

Comment: Why do you need to export certificates that are installed by default? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to read it in my library so my end-user can either load it into their http server or client, see here for the current implementation: https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart/blob/0b645763631541b38011c73794502de1b241914f/sslcontext-kickstart/src/main/java/nl/altindag/ssl/util/KeyStoreUtils.java#L198 I am already able to read `My` and `Root` but not the others from Java, so I am trying other methods.

Comment: You shouldn’t need every single certificate in the certificate store for your clients Apache server or client, you should only need, your actual singular certificate.

Comment: In an ideal situation yes. However If the client is calling different urls each like, for example if the client is used as a web crawler, then I would be more confortable to crawl only websites which have certificates that are trusted by Windows and skip not trusted websites. A different way is to trust all by disabling certificate validation which is not secure, but I don't prefer that.